# Access launcher using keyboard shortcut

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher

I want to access applications in the Launcher from keyboard. Although I have come across a few answers which says holing down the Super or the Windows key followed by the number in the order which it is arranged might do, but somehow that doesn't work in my case. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: whats your Ubuntu Version?

Comment: it's 18.04 @PRATAP